# Geometry changing vertical with \newgeometry for horizontal margin

Tags: geometry, page

I have a document with a defined set of margins and somewhere in the middle I need to add 1 cm to each of the side margins without changing the vertical layout. However, when I use `\newgeometry` to change the side margins the package also changes the value of `\topmargin`. For example, see this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[top=3.5cm,left=4.5cm,right=3.5cm,bottom=3.0cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\the\topmargin
\newgeometry{left=3.5cm,right=2.5cm}
\the\topmargin
\end{document}
```

It prints `-9.68535pt` on the first page and `-13.87262pt` on the second.

It looks like the package does not take the options in the preamble into account when recomputing the `\newgeometry`. Is this the expected behavior? Shouldn't the package “remember” the previous parameters and adjust only those necessary?

Comment: No, it doesn't remember.

Comment: @egreg Oh... So “expected (but not what I'd like) behavior” it is. Thanks :-) Do you want to add an answer or should I close as “solved in the comments”?